# Using recursion to find the number of 'hi' in a string but not 'xhi'

Tags: java, recursion

I am doing a problem from codingbat and I am stuck at this problem. The question asks me to find all the `'hi'` in the string but ignore the `'hi'` which have `'x'` just before them. In other words, don't count `'xhi'` but only `'hi'`.

Every input works fine in my code except for when the input is `"xxxx"`.
My code is as follows:

```
public int countHi2(String str) {
      String s = "hi";
      int count = 0;

      if(str.length() < 2) {
          return 0;
      }
      else if(str.charAt(0) == 'x' && str.substring(1,3).equals(s)) {
           count+= countHi2(str.substring(3));
      }
      else if(str.substring(0,2).equals(s)){
          count+= 1 + countHi2(str.substring(2));
      }
      else {
          count+= countHi2(str.substring(1));
      }
      return count;
}
```

The problem is that it throws IndexOutOfBoundsException. The link to the question can be found [here](http://codingbat.com/prob/p143900).

Comment: What do you get when you insert 'xxxx'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You see an exception because [`substring` throws `IndexOutOfBoundsException` if the beginIndex is negative, or endIndex is larger than the length of this String object, or beginIndex is larger than endIndex.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29) You check for the length to be at least 2, and then do `substring(1, 3)`, causing an exception.

You can avoid the problem with `IndexOutOfBoundsException` in `substring` by switching to `startsWith` API, which does not throw exceptions even when you compare your string to a longer one.

Comment: if the length of a string is 2, `substring(1,3)` will throw an exception as well...

Comment: @brimborium That's what the answer says, no?

Comment: @brimborium I stressed that point *after* your comment, thanks!

Comment: @dasblinkenlight i didn't use the startsWith() method but i learnt something new.... cheers

Answer (score 3):

You could do as follows :

```
public static int countHi2(String str) {
    if (str.startsWith("xhi")) {
        return countHi2(str.substring(3));
    } else if (str.startsWith("hi")) {
        return countHi2(str.substring(2)) + 1;  
    } else if (str.length() > 0){
        return countHi2(str.substring(1));
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

(It does not handles null value, and it is really not optimized.)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that if you have an 'x' at the end of your string (or at one of the last 2 positions), your substring will start at an index that is out of bounds (as your exception tells you). You could just check in that case, if `str.substring(3)` is feasible:

```
else if(str.charAt(0) == 'x' && str.substring(1,3).equals(s)) {
  if (str.length() > 3) count+= countHi2(str.substring(3));
  else return count;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

line no 8 need to modify.

```
else if(str.length()>=3 && str.charAt(0) == 'x' && str.substring(1,3).equals(s))
{...}
```

Total code should be -

```
public int countHi2(String str) {
  String s = "hi";
      int count = 0;

      if(str.length() < 2) {
          return 0;
      }
      else if(str.length()>=3 && str.charAt(0) == 'x' && str.substring(1,3).equals(s)) {
           count+= countHi2(str.substring(3));
      }
      else if(str.substring(0,2).equals(s)){
          count+= 1 + countHi2(str.substring(2));
      }
      else {
          count+= countHi2(str.substring(1));
      }
      return count;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Fixed one

```
public int countHi2(String str) {
    String s = "hi";
    int count = 0;

    if(str.length() < 2) {
        return 0;
    }
    else if(str.charAt(0) == 'x' && str.length() > 2 && str.substring(1,3).equals(s)) {
        count+= countHi2(str.substring(3));
    }
    else if(str.substring(0,2).equals(s)){
        count+= 1 + countHi2(str.substring(2));
    }
    else {
        count+= countHi2(str.substring(1));
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This code will perfome well for 'XXXX' and other combinations. But i haven't check for the all combinations.

```
public static int countHi2(String str) {
      String s = "hi";
      int count = 0;

      if(str.length() < 2) {
          return 0;
      }
      else if((str.length() >= 3) && (str.charAt(0) == 'x' && str.substring(1,3).equals(s))) {
           count+= countHi2(str.substring(3));
      }
      else if(str.substring(0,2).equals(s)){
          count+= 1 + countHi2(str.substring(2));
      }
      else {
          count+= countHi2(str.substring(1));
      }
      return count;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you never get to this line

```
return count;
```

you are using if else all the time
when your input is 'xxxx' you keep getting  to

```
count+= countHi2(str.substring(1));
```

Comment: Not true. His string gets smaller at every call and eventually, `if(str.length() < 2)` will return true and the recursion will be stopped. The problem is, that he is getting an exception before that can happen.

Answer (score 0):

when you have 2 letters remaining "xx" and you check the first condition, and you do `str.substring(1,3)` is when you get that error.
You should check that `str.lenght()` is not 2 in that case, for example:

```
public int countHi2(String str) {
    String s = "hi";
    int count = 0;

    if(str.length() < 2) {
        return 0;
    }
    else if(str.length()>2 && str.charAt(0) == 'x' && str.substring(1,3).equals(s)) {
         count+= countHi2(str.substring(3));
    }
    else if(str.substring(0,2).equals(s)){
        count+= 1 + countHi2(str.substring(2));
    }
    else {
        count+= countHi2(str.substring(1));
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you guys are complicating to much. here is a simple solution.

```
public int countHi2(String str) {
  return (str.length() < 2)?0:
         (str.substring(0,2).equals("xh"))?
           countHi2(str.substring(2)):
           (str.substring(0,2).equals("hi"))?
               1 + countHi2(str.substring(1)):
               countHi2(str.substring(1));   
}
```

or if it looks too weird :

```
public int countHi2(String str) {
   if(str.length() < 2)
     return 0;
   else if(str.substring(0,2).equals("xh"))
     return countHi2(str.substring(2));
   else (str.substring(0,2).equals("hi"))
     return 1 + countHi2(str.substring(1));
   else return countHi2(str.substring(1));   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have to use recursion:

```
public int countHi(String test) {
        if (test == null){
            return 0;
        }
        test = test.replaceAll("xhi", "");
        int n1 = test.length();
        int n2 = test.replaceAll("hi", "").length();
        return (n1-n2)/2;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code to fetch the count of 'hi' in a particular string.

```
public int countHi(String str) {
 int count = 0;
 int len = str.length();
 if(len<2) {
  return 0;
 }
 else {
   if(str.substring(0,2).equals("hi")) {
     return count+1+countHi(str.substring(2));
   }
   else {
     return count+countHi(str.substring(1));
   }
 }
}
```